# TortoiseSVN 1.7.6 Restore Unversion and add to ignore list files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Accidentally I have added a folder to "Unversion and add to ignore list" files. How to restore these file to repository again. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.
I just take clean up option then selects clean up working copy status and revert all changes recursively.